# Can't store NULL value inside MYSQL with table while the column is set to accept NULL value

Tags: php, mysql

I have s php script by which I insert data into my Table but when I put the **org_pid** column as empty or null I can't insert data and I have set **org_pid** to accept null value too but it doesn't accept. This is my php Script :

```
<?php

 register();

 function connectToDatabase(){
   $connection=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","database");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
mysqli_set_charset($connection,"utf8");
return $connection;
 }


function register(){

$connection = connectToDatabase();
$Username = $_REQUEST['Username'];
$Pass = $_REQUEST['Pass'];
$Email = $_REQUEST['Email'];
$Phone = $_REQUEST['Phone'];
$UserType= $_REQUEST['UserType'];
$OrgID= $_REQUEST['OrgID'];

if($Username!="" && $Pass!=""){

    $check = mysqli_query($connection,"select count(*) from user where usr_name='$Username'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($check);
    if($row[0]>=1){

        print "old_user";

    }else {

        $result = mysqli_query($connection,"insert into user (org_pid,usr_name,usr_email,usr_password,usr_phone,usr_type) values('$OrgID','$Username','$Email','$Pass','$Phone','$UserType')");

        if($result!=""){
            print "ok";
        }else if($result==""){
            print "no";
        }

        mysqli_close($connection);
    }

}else {
    print "null";
}

}

?>
```

And you can Check it by this [Link](http://shayea.tk/sof/test.html)!. Th link contains a simple html page linked to my php script

Comment: Pls share the table definition and the exact error message!

Comment: some error message would be nice, i suspect you put quote `'` around your so called `null`

Comment: But also note that `'null'` or `''` is not the same as `null`!

Comment: @Shadow check the question I edited and added table structure

Comment: @slier if you check my PHP script you will see that it doesn't produce error.
It checks the **else if** which is after the **result** query and prints no which means it can't insert data but when you insert some data in that column by the HTML page I mentioned above it inserts the data

Comment: And what if you printed a meaningful error message in the else if instead of `no`?

Comment: @Shadow Fixed it 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL code has hard-coded quotes around all values so it's plain impossible to insert `NULL`, no matter the values of external input. You need to be aware that `NULL` is keyword on its own and entirely different from `'NULL'` (which is just a string with a literal NULL text that doesn't have any special meaning).

You should solve all your problems by:

1. Using prepared statements rather than injecting data into your query
2. Assigning PHP null yourself on empty strings (since it's impossible to get real NULL from a an HTML form), e.g.:

   ```
   $Email = isset($_REQUEST['Email']) && $_REQUEST['Email']=!''
       ? $_REQUEST['Email']
       : null;
   ```